# Select node without a particular child

Tags: xslt, xpath, lxml

For example I have an XML sample like this

```
<a>
    <a1>A1</a1>
        <a11>A11</a11>
    <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
<a>
```

How can I use XPath to select node `a` contain only

```
<a>
    <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
<a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is flexible enough for you, but it should get you started

```
/a/a1 | a/text() | /a/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'a'))]
```

You can play around with it easily here: http://www.xpathtester.com/test

Comment: Not exactly what I want but I've been able to modify it. Thanks for the website too

Answer (score 1):

XPath is a query language for XML documents. This means that an XPath expression can only select a set of nodes and/or extract data.

**Remember**: An XPath expression can never cause modufication of the structure of an XML document (such as deleting a node).

**The answer is** that no XPath expression is going to select the node you want because there isn't such a node in the XML document.

What you want can easily be accomplished with XSLT and (not so easily) with XQuery:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'a1')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<a>
    <a1>A1</a1>
    <a11>A11</a11>
    <a2>A2</a2>     Text 
    <strong>text</strong> text... 
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a>
   <a2>A2</a2>     Text 
    <strong>text</strong> text... 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath:

```
//a[normalize-space(.)='A2 Text text text...']
```

Would only select:

```
<a>
    <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
</a>
```

---

XSLT Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
  <a>
    <a1>A1</a1>
    <a11>A11</a11>
    <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
  </a>
  <a>
    <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
  </a>  
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//a[normalize-space(.)='A2 Text text text...']"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
  <a>
   <a2>A2</a2>
    Text <strong>text</strong> text...
  </a>
```

Comment: Maybe because the XPath expression selects no node at all?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Maybe I misinterpreted the question. I thought the OP had 2 different `<a>` and only wanted to select one. In this case the xpath does select the `a` node. I added an example to illustrate my misinterpretation.

Comment: If the transformation in this answer is applied to the XML document provided in the question, the result is the empty string.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - I tried it with Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5, Saxon-HE 9.3, and Saxon-EE 9.3. All worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but you aren't applying the transformation on the XML document provided by the OP.

Comment: Thanks, but A2 and text are not fixed => won't works for other cases

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Like I said, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @qazplm4ever - You're welcome. I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @DevNull: Yes, it turns out I also was misled by the way the OP worded this problem.